# mariadb unable to connect remotely, or from the same machine if IP is provided

Tags: mysql, mariadb

At a loss here - my issue doesn't seem to follow the typical pattern

I've confirmed that my mariadb server is listening on all interfaces:

```
sudo mysqld --print-defaults
mysqld would have been started with the following arguments:
--datadir=/var/lib/mysql --socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock --symbolic-links=0 --user=mysql --port=22120 --tmp_table_size=2G --max_heap_table_size=2G --max_connect_errors=10000000 --max_connections=500 --skip-name-resolve --log-error=/var/log/mariadb/mariadb.log --general_log=1 --bind-address=0.0.0.0
```

Further confirmed by:

```
sudo netstat -ntlup | grep maria
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22120           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      7725/mariadbd
```

Users are set up like so:

```
MariaDB [(none)]> select user, host from mysql.user;
+-------------+-----------+
| User        | Host      |
+-------------+-----------+
| riskapi     | %         |
| mariadb.sys | localhost |
| mysql       | localhost |
| root        | localhost |
+-------------+-----------+
```

with the following permission:

```
MariaDB [(none)]> show grants for riskapi;
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Grants for riskapi@%                                                                                                              |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO `riskapi`@`%` IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '*49961540B53DD8F01176126848E90AA794A8C313' WITH GRANT OPTION |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.000 sec)
```

Connecting from the local machine without IP works fine:

```
mysql -u riskapi --password=<password>
MariaDB [(none)]> quit
```

Connecting from the local machine with IP does not:

```
mysql -h 10.2.15.202 -u riskapi --password=<password>
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on '10.2.15.202' (115)
```

Connecting from a remote machine does not work, but with a different error code:

```
mysql -h 10.2.15.202 -p 22120 -u riskapi --password=<password>
ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on '10.2.15.202' (111)
```

what am I doing incorrectly here? Googling mostly leads to answers that suggest bind-address should be commented out/explicitly set to "0.0.0.0" and i've done that (both options) and it still doesn't work.
I've turned on logging as well, but those logs aren't useful at all. Confirmed that firewalld is not running.

Comment: Maybe check if your mysql port is blocked and if the database settings allow remote acces.

Comment: Yeah, i can telnet to that host:port from the remote server just fine. I was under the impressions the bind-address is the only setting that enables/disable remote access? and mine is configured to allow it. Is there another setting i'm missing?

Comment: Some sources recommend commenting `skip-networking` out, too, right underneath `bind-address`.